# How to embed an external JavaScript from a JSF view

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

How can I embed an external JavaScript library like Google maps within a JSF view?

In traditional HTML I'd do it like `<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.6&sensor=false"></script>`.

I want to know if its compulsory to use  `< h:outputScript>` tag when I want to include an external JS library in a JSF view, because all examples I was able to find on this subject assumed that the actual JS file was included in a web application project and thus used `<h:outputScript>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can insert standard HTML elements in your JSF views, like `<div>` or `<script>`, as in your case. Moreover, JSF will ultimately render `<h:outputScript>` as a plain `<script>` element. We normally use the former to let the JS file *pass through the `FacesServlet`*.

All of this yields that your `<script>` element shall be inserted 'as is'.

Comment: thanks for your response. I actually had my code that way, just wanted to be sure if there was not an "official" jsf2 way to do it.